# How can I repair a drain that won't stop leaking?

Tags: water, leak, sink, drain

I have a kitchen drain that won't stop leaking.  I've checked, and it's definitely leaking from around the joins in the PVC pipe.  I've replaced several of the o-rings (washers), as well as the P trap (bend).  The pipes are all joined with o-rings and lock-nuts and they're as tight as my programmers hands can make them.

Is there anything else I should try before simply replacing the whole setup?

Comment: Washers? Like rubber washers?

Also, have you ensured that both ends of the pipe are evenly seated before tightening?  If both ends do not mate properly, you might be able to tighten it a bit, but you are not creating a proper seal.

Comment: @Steven yes rubber washers.  There are about nine joins involved (it's a double sink and it seems to have a extra join to this novice) so I'm not 100% I got them all mated properly.

Comment: im not a plumber, but i've never seen washers on any of my ABS fittings. It might be different with PVC... Try without them?

Comment: @Steven rubber "washers" on pvc traps and fittings are very common there are actually mostly o-rings and one (or two in the case of double bowl connecter) tapered flange washer check out this [link](http://wn.com/How_PVC_Compression_Fittings_Work__Plumbing_Tips) sorry about the video... but it does show the washers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Respectfully disagree with Shirlock.  OVER tightening of PVC joints damages them and causes leakage.

Hand tight is snug, not SO TIGHT YOUR HANDS HURT.

Take a look at this article for more information.
[The "Do's and Don'ts" of Assembling Threaded Plastic Fittings](http://www.lascofittings.com/supportcenter/TheDosandDontsThreadedPlastic.asp)

Comment: The article you linked mentioned "sealant".  Is that the same thing as cement?

Answer (score 0):

Try using some pump pliers and tighten them a bit mor than hand tight.  If that doesn't work, replace the main joints with PVC components that glue together. The only joint that should have a compression nut is the tail piece. Traps and other pipes with compression fittings sound like cheap hardware store quick fix parts.